# Binding variable in loop changes it's type

Tags: python, anonymous-function, nicegui

I'm trying to make some order in a script that uses nicegui. I'm using a dictionary to store all button labels and the pages they will redirect to.

I'm iterating over all keys in `pages` dictionary and calling `ui.button` for each of them.

```py
from nicegui import ui

pages = {'page_one':'Page','page_two':'Page 2','page_three':'Page 3'}

for page in pages:
    ui.button(pages[page], on_click=lambda page=page: ui.open(page))
```

when binding `page` it becomes a completely different type `nicegui.events.ClickEventArguments` instead of a normal string

not binding `page` causes all buttons to redirect to `page_three`

```py
ui.button(pages[page], on_click=lambda: ui.open(page))
```

I feel like I completely misunderstand what actually binding is and how lambdas operate.

Why is the `page` variable changing type when bound to function in this context?

Comment: Why do you think that `page` is not a string?

Comment: `lambda page:` isn’t “binding” anything; it makes the callback accept one argument, which is being passed at call time. You probably mean `lambda page=page`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'ClickEventArguments'` when running this code. I've also replaced ui.open with print to make sure

@deceze Yeah, that is what I meant. Both `lambda page=page` and `lambda page` caused the same error and I just didn't realize these were different actions.

Comment: Yes, the caller is still passing an argument which replaces the default argument, even when "bound". So your question really boils down to how to "bind" the variable correctly somehow in this loop; not that it changes type.

Comment: @deceze Yeah, it looks like the event handling inspects the signature of the callback. So if the callback is a lambda with no arguments, it's just called with no arguments; if the callback has an argument (even defaulted), the ClickEventArguments thing is passed to it. https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/blob/c30ed1f33d95dbb05ee5f9bdd175a22ed688cfdc/nicegui/events.py#L261

Answer (score 3):

NiceGUI automatically passes event arguments to event handlers - depending on whether they expect arguments or not. This way you can conveniently write something like

```py
def do_something():
    ui.notify('Doing something...')

ui.button('Do something', on_click=do_something)
```

without caring about possible event arguments.

But you can also accept and consume event arguments:

```py
def show_value(value):
    ui.notify(value)

ui.input(on_change=lambda e: do_something(e.value))
```

Now if you define an event handler like `lambda page=page: ui.open(page)`, NiceGUI tries to pass event arguments to the `page` parameter, because the lambda function *expects* arguments. In order to avoid overwriting the `page` argument with event arguments, you can insert another unused parameter, commonly denoted with `_`, that swallows the event argument while keeping the `page` untouched: `lambda _, page=page: ui.open(page)`.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the NiceGUI developers. And I'm thinking about whether NiceGUI could detect a case like `lambda page=page: ui.open(page)` and *not* passing event arguments, since all function parameters already have default values.

Comment: I just created [PR 965](https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/pull/965) to improve this behavior.